# Remove All Column Spacing in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

[image: Screen shot of my app with four columns.]

I have an app that takes a variable number of user names and builds a grid with two columns for each user.  The problem is, I want the columns in the grid to have no space between each other.  If they don't fill the screen, I'd like them to center on it.  I've tried every suggestion I could find on Stack Overflow, but nothing has worked so far.

I changed the column width, gravity, horizontal spacing, and stretch mode.  Are there any other values I'm missing that might help?

Here is the layout that includes my grid view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greetPlayers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Player Names Here"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/score_gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/greetPlayers" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scoreEntryWindow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="64dp"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the layout for each item in the grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="-15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backgroundCellImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_square" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foregroundCellContents"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="1,1" />
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

---

Edit 20 June: changing the items in the grid view to match parent, they are now centered in the extra-wide space, but still have the space.
[Link to new image - can't embed images in posts yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61jal.png)

Comment: have you tried adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your GridView?

Comment: I have, but it still has the same spacing.  When I click a cell, it also highlights the space next to it, so I'm now wondering if the problem's with the cell itself, not padding on the grid view, but not sure how that could be since it isn't adding vertical space and the image doesn't have a border.

Comment: Why are you using a GridView and not a RecyclerView ? Also dont set your columnWidth of your GridView

Comment: can you try to use `wrap_content` in your item LinearLayout instead of `match_parent`? Also keep the `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` untouched

Comment: I'm going to have animations off of this that my instructor said I should use GridView for instead of RecyclerView.  I removed columnWidth from GridView, kept android:adjustViewBounds="true" in the same, and changed "match_parent" to "wrap_content" in the LinearLayout and I still see the spacing.

Comment: Have you tried setting your framelayout to match_parent instead of wrap_content for your grid items?

Comment: That centered them in the extra-wide space, which makes it look better, but I still have really wide margins between them; didn't get rid of the margins.